# Arduino IDE + Metro + I2C device (Grideye) + Code for Uno = weird results?

Tags: i2c, camera

I have been working successfully with the arduino uno and a thermal camera device called grid eye. There is a board available at the popular suppliers of arduino addons.
For the uno, the code looks something like this and works.

```
// Load Grideye Library
#include <SparkFun_GridEYE_Arduino_Library.h>
uint8_t pixelTable[64];
void setup() {
    grideye.setI2CAddress(104); //This means, that one pin of the device is pulled up
    grideye.begin();
    Serial.begin(115200);
}
void loop() {
// loop through all 64 pixels on the device and map each float value to a number
// between 0 and 15 using the HOT and COLD values we set at the top of the sketch    
  for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    if (i % 8 == 0) {
      Serial.print("\n");
    }
    pixelTable[i] = grideye.getPixelTemperature(i);      
    Serial.print(pixelTable[i]);
    Serial.print(" ");
  }
```

For the Metro I use Arduino IDE with the Libraries installed and the board selected. But all I get is an Array full of '0'.

Connected, both times, to the designated SDA and SCL pins, as well as the 3.3V and GND Pin.

Any Ideas?

Comment: does I2CScaner sketch find the device?

Comment: what is the correct GridEye I2C address? ...... btw, do not use decimal numbers for the address, it can cause errors because all of the documentation is in hex or in binary

Comment: Thank you for your comments and sorry for initially posting in the wrong community.  I downloaded I2Cscanner, which does not find any devices. This, I don't understand, the UNO works fine with the same setup..   The Correct ist either 0b1101000 or 0b1101001, depending on whether one Pin is connected to GND or pulled up. MIe is connected to GND, so 0b1101000 or 104, or 0x68 it shold be  I changed to hex btw, also no effect.